# Run WordPress on ampps Windows

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, iis

I have installed IIS 7 on Windows 7 which uses 80 port, then I installed AMPPS, set up default port to 8095 in apache configuration file:

```
Listen 8095
```

and installed WordPress blog. Now when I try to run it:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8095/wpMyBlog/
```

or

```
http://localhost:8095/wpMyBlog/
```

it redirects it to

```
http://127.0.0.1/wpMyBlog/
http://localhost/wpMyBlog/
```

and says:

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

How to fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you enabled permalinks?

Comment: No, I didn't changed anything except port, I just installed as default

Comment: Check .htaccess file.